# why i'm not able to fetch api?

Tags: reactjs

```
 fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&appid={b4a02f3420e98aa54f5a688d40ce527b}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    setWeather(result);
    setQuery('');
    console.log(result);

  })
```

> Its showing error VM3131:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: can you try after removing `{` and `}` in appid?

Comment: i can't i checked the api call documentation when have to insert { and }

Comment: can you try to remove `response.json()` and instead console `respone` and check what output it returns?

Comment: its showing unauthorized 401

Comment: i have verified my api key from the email they sent

Comment: So that response is not json and you are trying to do `response.json()` that why it was throwing error. Try to find out why server is returning that. Most probably it's issue from server side. For more information on this error follow this: https://daveceddia.com/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/

Comment: @PriyankKachhela is right, your query should not have the { } around the appid. They are there in the docs to indicate that `{API key}` is a placeholder. (you should also regenerate your api key, since you've shared it here)

Comment: @Villa7_ its an argument not part of that string, its coming from user

Comment: `query` is an argument, but `b4a02f3420e98aa54f5a688d40ce527b` presumably is not. your full url would be `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&appid=b4a02f3420e98aa54f5a688d40ce527b`

Comment: i generated another key it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be changed:

- The openweathermap docs show `{API key}` as a placeholder, the actual url should not include the `{}` around your key
- The url you are `fetch`ing from should start with `https://`, otherwise it will try to fetch relative to the current origin.

```js
const query = 'Brooklyn'
fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&appid=b4a02f3420e98aa54f5a688d40ce527b`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a `$` after`appid=`

`` fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&appid=${b4a02f3420e98aa54f5a688d40ce527b}`) ``

Comment: what part you wanna see cause its lengthy. Actually i'm fetching it when someone enter a state in input bar and clicks enter

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed from postman to see whether the url is returning any data? Maybe the API key is incorrect and no data is coming back

Comment: should i generate another key?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the request header format should be define.
Would you like to run this code, please?

```
 fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&appid=b4a02f3420e98aa54f5a688d40ce527b`, {
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    setWeather(result);
    setQuery('');
    console.log(result);
  })
```

Let me know if it works or not.
Thanks.

Comment: this JSON file already have header, i dont need to add it here